# Find the int that appears an odd number of times in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The question is to find the integer that appears an odd number of time in an array 
ex: `[1,1,1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,1]` should return `10` and `[5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,10,10]` should return `1`.

My code pass all the test but these two. I have no idea why can anyone explain?

```
function findOdd(A) {
  var keyCounts = {};
  var topKey = {};
  A.forEach(function(item, val) {
    keyCounts[item] = keyCounts[item] + 1 || 1;
    if (keyCounts[item] % 2 !== 0) {
      topKey = item;
    } 
  });
  return topKey;
}
```

Comment: Putting a `console.log(item)` inside the `if` statement should shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because you check for the "odd" count while you're iterating over the array, so every time it finds *any* new number it'll overwrite `topKey`.

To solve, count the numbers first, and *then* iterate over the found `keyCounts` object to find which one was odd:

```
function findOdd(A) {
    let counts = A.reduce((p, n) => (p[n] = ++p[n] || 1, p), {});
    return +Object.keys(counts).find(k => counts[k] % 2) || undefined;
}
```

Comment: I check your solution but it failed for some cases. Ex: `[ 1, 1, 2, -2, 5, 2, 4, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]` should return `-1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think i solved it by iterating after counting. I added this line after counting. `for(var odd in keyCounts) {
    if (keyCounts[odd] % 2) {
      topKey = odd;
    }
  }`

Comment: @markchen555  you could just `return odd` in that `if`, to avoid testing the remaining numbers once a match is found

Comment: and I've fixed the bug - I had `A` in the `Object.keys` instead of `counts`

Comment: @markchen555 NB: your own code will return the string version of the number found.  The `+(string) || undefined` in my answer is there to ensure that the numeric value (or `undefined` if no match was found) is returned

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to *topKey* too soon, as the same value may occur one more time.

Here is a solution which adds/removes a value to/from a `Set` at every occurrence (like a toggle) and then takes the first value from the remaining Set:

```js
function getOdd(arr) {
    for (v of arr.reduce((set, v) => set.delete(v) ? set : set.add(v), new Set))
        return v;
}

var arr = [5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,10,10];
result = getOdd(arr);
console.log(result);
```